How to add a canonical tag using JavaScript in Next.js?
I want to add a canonical tag in my next js application but I'm stuck on this error,
67791:1 Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened. (anonymous)@67791:1
I have tried various approaches.
1. <Script
        src="//tags.orquideassp.com/--"
        strategy="--"
      />


2. useEffect(() => {
    
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//tags.orquideassp.com/---";
    script.async = false; 
    script.defer = false; 
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);


3. <Head>
   </Head>
   <script src="//tags.orquideassp.com/--" />

